# How to solve error A01100 while starting GridDB cluster

Tags: griddb

I have installed GridDB CE on my Ubuntu machine from https://griddb.net/en/downloads/. After setting up an admin user password and starting the node, I tried to join a cluster using the following command and I got an error.

```
gs_joincluster -u admin/password
```

The error I got was

```
A01100: Specified cluster name is wrong.
```

Did I miss anything in the setup process? I was following this video from GridDB.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WHcbhlQhc8I

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to specify the cluster name, execute command like this;

```
gs_joincluster -c yourClusterName -u username/pass
```